# Need help moving the mouse cursor relative using a Logitech G910

Tags: lua, macros, mouseevent, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to get some bog standard code to work on my Logitech G910 keyboard. It's nothing much...mostly it is used to help edit a shopping list on a website. To help remove one item at a time I simply have it left click, replace the current number (single digit item) with a 0, move the mouse relative to the right, click, press the up key five times, and move it relative back to the left so that it's in position.

Now I am well aware that I could just as easily change the code to move the mouse somewhere on the screen, and that's all well and good, but since this is a learning opportunity for me, I might as well exploit it for all it's worth for latter use in the future. That said this is the headache I'm having...when the cursor is moved relative to it's location on the screen that's one value, but to move it back into position that's a different value, or in this case if it's moved 100 to the right, it has to be moved -65 to the left to be in the same position. This, of course, makes no sense what-so-ever.

To add to the problem, as if this wasn't bad enough on it's own, the cursor doesn't always end up in the same place when the code is ran. Sure...it will be in place on the first execution of the code, but on the second it's out of place, third it might be in place, and the fourth it might be out of place, etc. While this is all a headache, I can at least say this much: when it comes to using relative commands it sure is nice to have it, especially where using an arrow key won't place it in the exact position it needs to be in. Slightly off mark? No problem...just have it go up -2 on the y axis and it's all golden. :D

That aside, to make things a little easier, here is the snippet of code that I am using.

```
if (event == "G_PRESSED" and mkey == 1 and arg == 3) then

--Delete the value and replace with a 0 on site

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)

Sleep(100)

PressAndReleaseKey("backspace")

PressAndReleaseKey("0")

Sleep(100)

MoveMouseRelative(100, 0)

PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)

Sleep(100)

PressAndReleaseKey("up")

PressAndReleaseKey("up")

PressAndReleaseKey("up")

PressAndReleaseKey("up")

PressAndReleaseKey("up")

Sleep(200)

MoveMouseRelative(-65, -2)

end
```

Comment: `the cursor doesn't always end up in the same place` - Try making 10 steps 10 pixels per step with 15 ms intervals between steps (instead of single jump over 100 pixels)

Comment: I tested out what you suggested, and too my surprise, it worked! As a test I tried the same thing with five sets of 20 rather than 10 sets with 10, and it worked as well, so that's nice to know in terms of code efficiency and time saved (no matter how minor). My only question though is *why* does it work? I mean, yes, it works, but the why is just as important as the how.

[Bird flight powered by faulty code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRQhJ.jpg

Anyway, thanks for the help, you've managed to help me a lot today. :D

Comment: `why does it work?` - GUI system does not expect such unrealistically fast mouse movements.